Firebase Notification causing blank tab in Chrome on Windows OS when focusing on already open tab
I'm encountering an issue with Firebase Notifications specifically in Chrome on Windows OS. When I attempt to focus on an already open tab using the notification, the tab goes blank. This issue doesn't seem to occur on other browsers or operating systems.
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
var redirectURL = event.notification.data;
event.waitUntil(
    clients
        .matchAll({
            includeUncontrolled: true,
            type: 'window',
        })
        .then((clientsArr) => {
            console.log(clientsArr);
            let isFocused = false;
            for (var client of clientsArr) {
                var redirectPath = new URL(redirectURL);
                var clientPath = new URL(client.url);
                if (clientPath.origin === redirectPath.origin) {
                    const clientConversationId =
                        clientPath.pathname.split('/')[
                            clientPath.pathname.split('/').length - 1
                        ];
                    const redirectConversationId =
                        redirectPath.pathname.split('/')[
                            redirectPath.pathname.split('/').length - 1
                        ];
                    if (clientConversationId === redirectConversationId) {
                        //same conversation
                        isFocused = true;
                        client.focus();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!isFocused || !clientsArr.length) {
                console.log('Opening new window');
                return clients.openWindow(redirectURL);
            }
        }),
);
event.notification.close();});

Problem:
When the notification click event is triggered and the code attempts to focus on an already open tab, the tab goes blank.
Expected behavior:
The tab should retain its content when focused, as expected.
Environment:
Operating System: Windows
Browser: Chrome
Additional notes:
This issue seems to be specific to Chrome on Windows OS. I've tested it on other browsers and operating systems, and the problem does not occur.
